# Get page's Creator infirmation from Tridion CMS

Tags: 2011, core-service

I am building a feedback form, when user summit the feedback I need to send an email.
I need to get "creator" information of the current page which will be used in sending email.
I have page's TCM ID in metadata tag, what is the best approach to get page's "creator" information from Tridion CMS.

I am thinking on following 2 approaches.

1. Publish creator's information in page's metadata tag during publishing pipeline and use that information in email process.
2. Get TCM id from metadata and use client core service to query Tridion and get creator's information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not like option 2 - it looks like you would have to open the CoreService up to the CD side. Sure you can protect it, but it complicates the setup.

Option 3: Store the feedback in an Amazon SQS/Azure  Queue Storage, then have a windows service on the CM side pull the information over. This CM service would have access to the Core Service without having to expose the Core Service to the outside. You can of course also store the data directly on the CD side, but then you have to implement the queue yourself... which sounds like work.

That said, I would probably go with option 1. :)